# Submitting image to Laravel 5.5 via post request with API Blueprint

Tags: php, json, laravel, post, apiblueprint

Trying to do something pretty simple but just need a bit of specific knowledge to get it to work.

I'm trying to submit an image in a post request to a post route in Laravel 5.5.

While retrieving a file from a request is easy with something like `$file = $request->file('filename');`,

Which will work with a html5 form that uploads a file and submits it to that route, what I am trying to do is upload a file via an API Blueprint.

I've unsuccessfully tried looking for the exact post data structure Laravel expects in order for a file to be retrieved with `$file = $request->file('filename');`,

Which I'm guessing is a standard, yet I have been unable to find an example of it as an API Blueprint.

If anyone has any pointers or suggestions, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

submit an image in a post request to a post route in Laravel 5.5 use this code:

```
$imageTempName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getPathname();
$imageName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getClientOriginalName();
```

I think you need to try this process for upload file into the database within the directory using Laravel 5.

```
<?php
public static function upload_file(Request $userdata){
    $imageTempName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getPathname();
    $imageName = $userdata->file('image_media')->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = base_path() . '/public/uploads/images/';
    $userdata->file('image_media')->move($path , $imageName);
    $data=array('media'=>$imageName);
    $insert=with(new UserModel)->uploadFile($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: This is the part I have working, what I'm actually having difficulty with is submitting a file via an API Blueprint to the post route. I'm able to submit an image with a html form, but I just can't quite snag the format/structure laravel wants the request to be in when creating the API Blueprint. Thanks for the response though!